# IA32 Immediate operand

Tags: x86

```
    MOV     AL, 13
    MOV     AL, 0xD
    MOV     AL, 0Ah + 3 ;Note leading 0 to distinguish from register AH
    MOV     AL, 7 * 2 - 1
```

Ok I understand that this example shows that all 4 equate to 13 but how does 0Ah + 3 = 13? I've never seen this format before.

Answer (score 0):

Conner,

This is not a reference to the AH register, but the hex for 10.  0Ah is equal to 0xA so it is basically just saying 10+3 using 2 different numeric bases.